# Regex / C# String - Pseudo Wildcards into an Array

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create some wildcards in strings in C#.    So an end-user can fill up a glob of text with wildcards.    Imagine:

```
var targetString = 
@"There is a banana in this %%object%%.   
For this, we use %%type of tool%% to remove it.";
```

Assuming the `%%` is the wildcard delimiter.   The code would parse looking for the first %% and following %% and determine that the wildcards are `object` and `type of tool`.   Getting them back as a string array would be spiffy, doesn't really matter as long as I can iterate through all the pseudo wildcards in the text.

Can someone give me a clue with some regex (or C# string manipulation) to come at this cleanly?   I could certainly bust out my old VBScript approach and start splitting this string based on %% -- but that's awfully inefficient, and I suspect there's a simpler approach using Regex on the C# string.

Comment: Use regex to find matching groups.
[Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sometime, basic approaches are more performant than more sophisticated ways. It is not always true, but it needs to be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = Regex.Matches(targetString, @"%%(.+?)%%").Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like `%%([^(%%)].*?)%%` and get the matched group at index 1.

String literals for use in programs:

```
 @"%%([^(%%)].*?)%%"
```

The regex means `%%` followed by any thing until `%%` is found.

Here parenthesis `()` is used for grouping. I have tested it [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to build some sort of templating system. Rather than rolling your own, you might want to look at readily available template engines such as  [`StringTemplate`](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

ST lets you do things like this:

```
using Antlr4.StringTemplate;

Person person = new Person() ;
person.Name = "John" ;
person.Street = "123 Main St" ;
person.City   = "Anytown" ;
person.Zip    = 12345 ;

Template hello = new Template("Hello. My name is <p.Name>. My Address is <p.Street>, <p.City>,  <p.State> <p.Zip>.");

hello.Add("p", person);
Console.Out.WriteLine(hello.Render());
```

And get the expected text written to the console:

```
Hello. My Name is John. My address is 123 Main St, Anytown, PA 12345.
```

Nice!